# How to use the sed command to delete a line from a file

Tags: linux

Hello I am trying to delete a line from my file but I keep getting this error when i run the command below: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command

Here is an example of what I am trying to do

```
sed -i 'something'/d "home/file/something.txt"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `/` at the beginning of the pattern.

```
sed -i '/something/d' "home/file/something.txt"
```

Comment: Cmon. Vote to close as typo...